# Moving parent window with popup window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, popup, window

I would like to have a popup window in the center of a movable parent window.
I created a new borderless window with `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner` and the `Owner` property is set at runtime.

Following should happen: The popup window will appear and the background is blurred out. When I move the parent window then the popup window should alway stay centered relative to the parent window.

1. If I use `ShowDialog()` the parent window will not be movable.
2. If I use `Show()` the parent window is moveable but the popup window will stay on the spot.
3. And because of the blur effect I am not able to create a canvas and just make it visible because this will also be blurred out.

I know I could use the LocationChanged-Event to constantly calculation the new position of the popup window. Same I must do when the parent window is resized. 
But I thought that maybe someone of you guys has a more elegant way to accomplish my intention?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does the popup have to be a true Window or Popup?  Could it be a faux window in an adorner layer or something?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. I just want some input from the user and then  it will disappear again. Will it let blur out only the background? Or btw. what is a faux window?

Comment: "faux" means "fake".  Not a real popup, but something that acts enough like one to get the job done.